# БД +приложение+интерфейс

Tags: java, база-данных, сервер, веб-сервер

У меня есть простенькая база данных MySQL, в которой одна таблица и несколько хранимых процедур. Мне нужно сделать серверное приложение для вызова этих процедур + интерфейс (простая html страница) для отображения данных БД. 
Собираюсь сделать на java. В IntelliJ IDEA сделал проект maven, там сделал простенький класс для подключения к бд с помощью jdbc. Коннект есть, запросы тоже написать могу, но не совсем понимаю как это должно работать? Мне нужен какой то веб-сервер (я так понял Tomcat подойдет), и html страница, но как это всё соединить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть куча tutorial на просторах интернет. Мне например помогло эти 2-а видео: [Spring BOOT + Maven + SpringMVC + thymeleaf  CRUD application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VS8W-tEqIiw)

Вообще гугл гораздо лучше меня это все знает, вбейте: CRUD Maven Tomcat tutorial